# Very basic questions about digital art programs

Tags: images

I am unfortunately very stupid and after several hours struggle have not made any progress, so I'm hoping someone can help me out. I'm not an artist but need to do some basic image editing-type things for a project.
I would like to:

- be able to draw a line on an image and then resize the entire image such that the line is 6 inches long (or whatever)
- convert a simple black-and-white png to vector form

Are there programs that would be able to do either of these things? I expect to do a lot of googling of tutorials but I don't even know where to start. Any help is deeply appreciated - I think I actually understand *less* than I did when I started trying to learn this morning.

Comment: Welcome to **GDSE** - please have a look around [tour] to learn about who and what our community is. Please also look at [ask] and [answer] a question, to best understand how to frame queries to get the best responses. You *may* find that some folks tag your question as it's initially written as "overly broad" - I think after reading the info in the links I've provided, were I you, I'd consider a bit of refining work on your question to make it a tad less broad a good investment as you'll also get better quality answers!

Answer (score 6):

For resizing the images, you should be searching for any "Photo Editor".

A very popular program is [Photoshop](https://www.adobe.com/products/photoshop.html), it is not a free program, though Adobe offers a 7 day [free trial](https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/photoshop?promoid=61PM825Y&mv=other).

A free and open-source alternative is [Gimp](https://www.gimp.org/)

Not sure why you need to draw the line, but you can also just resize the image if that's what you're looking for.

---

For tracing the image into vector, you will need to use a *vector* artwork software.

Again you have the option to use [Illustrator](https://creative.adobe.com/products/download/illustrator.html), which is paid and has a 7 day free trial.

Or you can use a very popular free and open-source alternative - [Inkscape](https://inkscape.org/).

If it is very simple as you say, you can easily recreate it using the pen tool or something.